# SonarQube code coverage for .NET Core possible with sonar.genericcoverage.reportPaths?

Tags: .net, sonarqube

I've been looking at SonarQube for our CI pipeline, but quickly realized that
SonarQube doesn't support .NET Core yet. However, can someone tell me if it is
at least possible to use the /d:sonar.genericcoverage.reportPath flag together with DotCover and xunit to get code coverage for our projects?

EDIT: im using sonarserver v. 5.6.5 so IF it's possible i expect to use the Generic Test Coverage plugin for my server

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up just trying my luck to see if the above idea would work. 
However, i can more or less conclude that it won't because SonarQube just outputs

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe : No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.
```

When it can't find any files it can analyse. So .NET Core projects will have to wait to benefit from SonarQube it would seem :)